# scala: Cannot check match for unreachability

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I'm migrating an app from play 2.0.4 to play 2.1

But the following code raises this warning:

```
def toConditionOperator(value: String): ConditionOperator.Value = {
  if (value==null) {
    ConditionOperator.Unknown
  } else {
    value.toLowerCase match {
      case "equal" | "=" | ":"             => ConditionOperator.Equal
      case "notequal" | "!=" | "!:" | "<>" => ConditionOperator.NotEqual
      case "greaterorequal" | ">="         => ConditionOperator.GreaterOrEqual
      case "greater" | ">"                 => ConditionOperator.Greater
      case "lessorequal" | "<="            => ConditionOperator.LessOrEqual
      case "less" | "<"                    => ConditionOperator.Less
      case "between"                       => ConditionOperator.Between
      case "in"                            => ConditionOperator.In
      case "startswith"                    => ConditionOperator.StartsWith
      case "endswith"                      => ConditionOperator.EndsWith
      case "contains" | "$"                => ConditionOperator.Contains
      case "missing" | ""                  => ConditionOperator.Missing
      case "unknown" | _                   => ConditionOperator.Unknown
    }
  }
}


[info] Compiling 98 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to /home/sas/tmp/ideas-ba/webservice/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[warn] /home/sas/tmp/ideas-ba/webservice/app/utils/query/ConditionParser.scala:203: Cannot check match for unreachability.
[warn] (The analysis required more space than allowed. Please try with scalac -Dscalac.patmat.analysisBudget=512 or -Dscalac.patmat.analysisBudget=off.)
[warn]       value.toLowerCase match {
[warn]             ^
```

In play 2.0.4 (with scala 2.9.1) it worked ok, with this version (scala 2.10) it yields this warning

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's wrong. Which part of it don't you understand?

Comment: well, I was wondering why it worked ok with play2.0.4, and where could I pass the -D... params to avoid that warning

Comment: They changed the pattern matching code in 2.10, which is why the behaviour changed. As to whats the problem, I dont know...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe [this?](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/1134)

<s>What happens if you add</s>

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Dscalac.patmat.analysisBudget=1024")
```

to your `project/Build.scala`?

**[UPDATE / CORRECTION]**

I was wrong about `scalacOptions` - `-D` options need to be passed as JVM arguments, not arguments to `scalac`.  Since `sbt`/`play` respect the `JAVA_OPTS` environment, variable, maybe you could try running `play` or `sbt` like this?

```bsh
JAVA_OPTS="-Dscalac.patmat.analysisBudget=off" sbt
# Or
JAVA_OPTS="-Dscalac.patmat.analysisBudget=off" play
```

That's assuming you are on a Unix-y OS.

Comment: Tried a similar program with 2.10.0-RC2 and confirmed that passing `-Dscalac.patmat.analysisBudget` does indeed fix the problem.

Comment: Does anyone know how to set this on heroku or any hosting cloud?

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into the same issue(but not in Play).  For a more permanent fix simply create a file `~/.sbtconfig`, and add these lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
SBT_OPTS="-Dscalac.patmat.analysisBudget=off"
```

This file and the `SBT_OPTS` defined inside it will be used every time you run `sbt`.  Depending on where you got Play from it might be bundled with its own version of sbt and may not use this file at launch time.

Answer (score 1):

For '**per project**' SBT configuration add this to your `.scala` build file.

```
initialize ~= { _ => sys.props("scalac.patmat.analysisBudget") = "off" }
```

Answer (score 0):

For sbt 0.13.* adding -J scalac option in build.sbt works for me:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Jscalac.patmat.analysisBudget=off")
```

or

```
sbt -J-Dscalac.patmat.analysisBudget=off
```

or you can add the option with "-J" to the global options file: /usr/local/etc/sbtopts